# style.css what is media?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to build a website and recently I've been trying to modify something in my style.css file which I did. The problem is that the style.css file that I modified is not the style.css file that my website uses. After inspecting which style.css my website was using I found out this :

my website uses this : style.css?ver=17.7.4?media=1646744398 which seems to be a style.css file that I did not modify, but if I remove from the URL the media part to be left with style.css?ver=17.7.4? I get the style.css with the modifications I made.

When I go to my file manager in my theme folder and search for my style.css there is only one and it is the one I modified so how do I modify the style.css?ver=17.7.4?media=1646744398 because it seems like it doesn't even exist.

After doing what was written in the answer : https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-versioning-to-update-your-cached-wordpress-content
my issue remained but I saw one thing that changed.

When I inspected the badges again I saw this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChKLI.png)

And what you can't see on this picture is that the incorrect part is ver=17.7.4 and correct part is ver=6.0 so it seems like there is now a new version of my style.css file but my website still uses the wrong one

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: So, what I want to do on my website is to change the size of mycred badges (mycred is a wordpress plugin) and in order to do so I must change something in my style.css file which I did. This is the part of the code from the style.css file that I needed to change : .rh_mycred-users-badges img, #mycred-users-badges img{width: 30px; height: 30px; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 5px 0 0;} in this code, I simply needed to change 30px to 70px so that my badge was bigger. So i did. BUT when I inspect the badges on my website I see that the code is still 30px not 70px

Comment: the weird thing is that when I go to my file manager and check in the style.css code, I find .rh_mycred-users-badges img, #mycred-users-badges img{width: 70px; height: 70px; border-radius: 50%; margin: 0 5px 0 0;} but when I click on the style.css file from the inspect tool when I inspect the badges, I get the old code with 30px and not 70px. When I click on the style.css file that the inspect tool shows me, I get this one : style.css?ver=17.7.4?media=1646744398 BUT there is only one style.css file in my file manager and it is the one that I modified, this one doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to uncache the content WordPress cached. https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-versioning-to-update-your-cached-wordpress-content

Comment: unfortunately it did not change anything

Comment: Interesting. Could you try the following steps? Open developer tools (hit f12), go to network tab, mark "Disable Cache" checkbox, hit ctrl + f5, find and select the line for style.css then check the response.

Comment: Because of what you told me I tried to clear cache of my website including CSS files but it did not change a thing either

Comment: Maybe it is some WordPress thing. Could you check this link? https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-versioning-to-update-your-cached-wordpress-content Second title looks related.

Comment: I will delete the comments and update the answer with the link above which seems to be the best bet.

Comment: SO! Thank you very much for your help! It was indeed the answer you provided that was good, it created a new version that I could see when I inspected the badges, the thing was that my website was still using the old version (17.7.4) and not the new one that I could create thanks to your answer, therefore I went to my functions.php file and replaced the version it should use by the new one and that fixed my problem! THANK YOU

Comment: This is what I would have looked at first:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/

I'm a bit late but I'm glad you got it sorted already! :) Failing that, I would then have looked to see if the theme had some caching that was built into the theme.

Welcome by the way!

Comment: Glad to be helpful :)